# jQuery with json displaying in a list

Tags: jquery, json

How do I display json data in a list using jQuery?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


 $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {

     $.each(data.example, function(key, value) {
               
               var output="";
                output="<li>" + data.example[key].name + "</li>";

                $('#example').append(output);
                
    });

      });
          }
```

This doesn't seem to display anything.

Comment: you need: 1) a better formatting of your question;  2) to write the full code you use.

Comment: just added code

Comment: sorry the system messed up and wouldn't let me add code

Comment: I doubt the system messed up.  It is used daily by thousands of users.

Comment: Do you have an HTML element with an id of `example`? can you show us your HTML? - Also, you do have the file `'example.json'` placed on the folder as your HTML, right? (and you are using a server to ask for this file, right?)

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
        var output = '';
        $.each(data.example, function(key, value) {
            output += '<li>' + value.name + '</li>';
        });
        $('#example').html(output); // <ul id="example"></ul>
    });
});
```

UPDATE: Working JSON file

```
{
    "example": [
        {
          "name": "Dr. Sammie Boyer",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Eladio Beier",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Hilton Borer",
          "email": "Reva.Goyette@yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Rebekah do you have an HTML element with an id of `example`? can you show us your HTML?

Comment: <ul id="example">
    <li id="name" name="name" class="allexamples"></li>
</ul>

Comment: Your JSON file is the problem. I'll update the answer in a minute to see working JSON data.

Comment: I have also removed 'ul' tag, since your #example element is already 'ul'

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of syntax errors.  The comma in the each function is in the wrong place and there's no closing ); at the end.  The code below should work correctly...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


 $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {

     $.each(data.example, function(key, value) {

               var output="";
                output="<li>" + data.example[key].name + "</li>";

                $('#example').append(output);

    });

      });
          });
```

Comment: instead of using `data.example[key].name` you could use `value.name` - and instead of appending in every iteration of the loop, I'd concatenate the string and only append after the loop for improved performance.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: @Rebekah have a look at Wizard's answer

Comment: I did and it doesn't seem to work, no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: do you have an example of the .json file you are processing? Perhaps the error is there?

Comment: Sorry just seen example above

Answer (score 0):

This would be my take.

You have multiple syntax errors (which are hard to see because the code is poorly formatted) - formatting the code helps you see those errors.

Note: I avoided making the AJAX call to get the JSON data for the looping parsing example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {
    "example": [{
      "name": "Dr. Sammie Boyer"
    }, {
      "name": "Eladio Beier",
      "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
    }, {
      "name": "Hilton Borer",
      "email": "Reva.Goyette@yahoo.com"
    }]
  };

   
  
// we don't have to get the json in an AJAX call for this demo
// $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
      var output = "<ul>";
    
      $.each(data.example, function(key, value) {
        output += "<li>" + value.name + "</li>";
      });
      
      output += "</ul>";
      $('#example').append(output);;
// });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```